# Starting and stopping a secondary non-UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm rebuilding one of my WinForms applications in WPF, and I've encountered an issue with threading. I start the thread from a method in my UI class, such as a button click:

```
workerThread = new Thread(() => Engine.Start());
workerThread.Start();
```

The workerThread method follows this kind of general format:

```
static class Engine 
{
    public static bool RunThread = true;
    public static void Start()
    {
        while (RunThread)
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This is a loop that will constantly output data to a USB device. I only ever want this thread to end when I change my RunThread variable to false from elsewhere in the program. The issue lies in waiting for the thread to finish. If I close my MainWindow, the thread will continue until it tries to start a new loop and then quits, which means it might make calls to portions of the MainWindow that don't exist any more since it's being destroyed. If I run workerThread.Join(); the entire application freezes and becomes completely unresponsive.

Previously, I had set up something of this sort in my FormClosing method, to ensure it would wait for the thread to quit before moving on to other cleanup operations:

```
if (workerThread != null) {
    // Ask the thread to destroy itself
    Engine.RunThread = false;

    // If the thread is busy, wait for it to end
    while (workerThread.IsAlive)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
};
```

It's not the most graceful, but in WinForms it made sure the thread exited cleanly and then moved on. Trying something like this in WPF, however, just causes it to get stuck in the *while* loop; as I think it's blocking the thread from continuing and closing itself. Of course, I had to remove the *Application.DoEvents();* since that doesn't exist in WPF.

My suspicion is that I'm not creating this thread using the best techniques available in WPF, so my question is this: What's the best way to launch this thread so that I can safely exit it (and potentially start a new instance) later?

Comment: i suggest you use task instead of thread

Comment: Your suspicion is incorrect. What you need is a background thread. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Nothing I've been able to find on this website has shown me how to run a thread such as this. If this is a duplicate, of what is it?

Comment: @Elestriel see the linked answer. `workerThread.IsBackground = true;` is all you need here. Simple as that.

Comment: @HighCore: that will terminate the thread when the application ends and does not solve OP's question. Think like this: the background thread is saving data, the main thread terminates. This will terminate the background thread, potentially leaving the saved data corrupted.

Comment: Due to my explanation above, I vote for reopen. However, there might be other duplicates.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if that is the case, the OP should handle the MainWindow's Closing, or the Application's ShutDown, toggle the flag and join the background thread. Creating a secondary UI thread has nothing to do with any of that.

Comment: @HighCore This isn't supposed to be a secondary UI thread. It's a worker thread that constantly sends data to a USB device. It can be started and stopped dynamically within the program, and needs to be stopped before my program's MainWindow is closed. I've tried using workerThread.IsBackground = true and it doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do at all.

Comment: This is probably a design question: why do you allow the worker thread direct access to the UI? The worker thread should notify the controller and the controller should decide what to do. In case the UI is up and running, the controller would notify the view to update. In case the UI is closed, it would just discard the newly arrived USB data.

Comment: The only access that the worker has to the UI is through a delegate that posts output to a log textbox. Otherwise, the thread should just be sending data over USB based on certain parameters in the UI, which are bound to properties.settings on the UI side.

Comment: Check out `Progress<T>`. It shouldn't matter if UI thread ends, at that point the worker is just firing events that no one is listening to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people in the comments have noted, use a `Task` instead of a `Thread`.

```
Task workerTask = Task.Run(() => Engine.Start());
```

To make the UI wait with closing until the `Task` finished executing, handle the `Closing` event of the `Window` and wait until `workerTask` finished.

```
private async void NavigationWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    await workerTask;
}
```

Comment: I've actually encountered a new issue with this method. Seeing as the new task is an endless loop (at least, until I tell it to end) it completely freezes the UI thread. If I use `Thread.Sleep()` in the task, it lets the UI update, but that's not exactly an idea solution. Do you know what I could do to fix this?

Comment: it should not freeze the UI thread, because its a new thread. Are you communicating from the UI thread with the task in a blocking manner?

Comment: There's no communication between the thread and UI once the thread is running, other than that `RunThread` variable I'd mentioned in my OP. 

It's somewhat confusing, to be honest. I've tried running it as a `Task`, as a `BackgroundWorker`, and as a `Thread` using `isBackground = true` and `false`, and all of them block.

Comment: This should not be the case, maybe something else in the setup is wrong. Create a new question for it, so you can present your code better and then it is easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I try to solve my problems myself. My OP was kind of an act of desperation after hours of trying different things! I figured out the problem I mentioned in the comments; it had to do with updating the colour of some buttons on the main window. I'll have to figure out a better way to do it! Thanks again for your help.